# Has anyone successfully converted an Android app using GPS over to Blackberry PlayBook using the Eclipse plugin

Tags: android, gps, location, blackberry-playbook

I have tried converting my functional android app that uses GPS over to the Playbook and it compiles, loads, and runs on the device, but hangs trying to access the GPS.  I have figured out that there should be a user prompt displayed asking for permission to access the GPS location, but it never appears.  I am using the android permission "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" and have tried coarse also, but I cannot get that user prompt to show up.  Also, the app is not listed in settings >> security >> application permissions.

GPS does work on the device with other apps and I am NOT using Google Maps API's

Has anyone successfully done this with GPS, and if so, what permissions or work-arounds did you have to use.
Thanks

Comment: For me everything works. I am using mapquest + GPS. I don´t remember any user prompt, but my app get GPS location. It works with Eclipse+convert. I have not yet tested to put this app on AppWorld.

Comment: @OndraMorský Thanks for the reply.  I have given up on this issue, and Blackberry development in general.  After using the PlayBook for over a month, I have decided I don't care for it.

Comment: I understand. The Android runtime seems to have more bugs than features. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're side-loading the app onto the device you don't get the prompt about permissions, nor will your app appear in the Security->Application Permissions section. See [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/GPS-permission-in-android-app-to-bar-file/td-p/2349121) for details.

Can't blame you for giving up on the Playbook though - it's a complete pain to develop on, as are all the other BlackBerry platforms!